# NSNumber precision after formatting into string

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, floating-point-precision

I have NSNumber, that contains value and NSNumberFormatter, that converts NSNumber into NSString. I need to display NSNumber value on screen. To avoid screen overflow I set NSNumberFormatterStyle as Scientific, if NSNumber value more than 10^9. But there one more problem. If NSNumber value have fraction digits, then output looks like "14562442.9...".

I want to do dynamic precision for fixed character count. For example:

1 555 234 452

1 555 234.452

1 555 2344.52

It can be done by using %g operator for float type, but I think, that here can be more clean solution.

---

Here is my solution:

```
[resultFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[resultFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
NSInteger integerDigitsCount = [[resultFormatter stringFromNumber:resultNumber] length];
if ([[resultFormatter stringFromNumber:resultNumber] length] > 11) {
    [resultFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
    [resultFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
}
else {
    [resultFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
    if ([[resultFormatter stringFromNumber:resultNumber] length] > 11) {
        [resultFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [resultFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:11 - integerDigitsCount];
    }
    else {
        [resultFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [resultFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
    }
}
```

Comment: Write your own custom formatter? I do not think the existing `NSNumberFormatter` supports what you want.

Comment: It's obvious. But I dont know, how can I modernize NSNumberFormatter so that it did what I need. Now I have just one idea: set maximumFractionDigits to (11 - integer digits count) with each output. As I said, I think that's here can be something better.